# Null pointer exception when calling setOnClickListener()

Tags: android, kotlin

I am confused by this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method `void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)` on a null object reference
        at 

    com.example.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:20)
```

It says that this is the problem:
Mainactivity.kt:

```
package com.example.myapplication

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        goToAddProduct.setOnClickListener {
            startActivity(Intent(this,AddProductActivity::class.java))
        }
    }
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Add the logcat error and activity and xml code , to investigate it further

Comment: You need to initialize `goToAddProduct` on which you are setting click listener.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following

```
Button goToAddProduct = findViewById(R.id.id_of_product_in_xml);
```

and then use the onclick like this

```
goToAddProduct.setOnClickListener {
        startActivity(Intent(this,AddProductActivity::class.java))
    }
```

Comment: Kindly Upvote if answer was helpful to you